# insert data into text widget in a For loop, tkinter python3

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

i am new to Python + tkinter

I am trying to enter values into a text widget using FOR loop

The problem is, text widget not showing anything during For loop execution. When for loop finishes, it shows all values.

How can I show inserted values during for loop.

See last line of code

```
for item in liList:
        listDict = {}
        # get a tag href
        listATag = item.find_all("a", attrs={"class": "product-image"})[0]
        listATagHref = listATag['href']
        listDict["purchaseLink"] = listATagHref

        imgPageRequest = requests.get(listATagHref)
        imgPageData = imgPageRequest.text
        imgPageSoup = BeautifulSoup(imgPageData, 'lxml')
        try:
            productImgDiv = imgPageSoup.find_all('div', attrs={"class": "product-image"})[0]
            imgATag = productImgDiv.find_all('a')[0]['href']
            largeThumbFileName = (imgATag.split('/')[-1])
            tempImgNameList.append(largeThumbFileName)
            print(listATagHref)
            textBox.insert(END,listATagHref+'\n')
            etc...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `update` on the widget you are adding new data to, for it to refresh and show the new values after each iteration. This is as the Tk `mainloop` will normally catch the new information on your widget and update it, but when you are in a loop such as this, it cannot check until after the loop is finished.

If `root` is what you define to be `Tk()`, then you can call `root.update()`, or on the actual widget itself. This would go at the end of your `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

aside from updating the window, or the text widget you can change the first argument of your textbox from END to INSERT.

```
import tkinter as tk
# inside the try block change the first argument to INSERT 
textBox.insert(tk.INSERT,listATagHref+'\n')
```